# Pandas Exponential Moving Average (ewm) weight "persists" through the entire DataSeries?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reduce the processing time when computing EWMs on a pandas data series by filtering the most "recent" values (and ensuring that there are enough values to do so), but it seems that the weight is updated for every single row and not "reseted" in each window as i expected, what i mean by that is, consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nvalues = 2**26
window_size = 256
values = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(0, 1, nvalues))
```

Having this Series, i would now like to compute the exponential moving average using:

```
values.ewm(span=window_size, min_periods=window_size).mean()
```

which gives me something like this:

```
0                NaN
1                NaN
2                NaN
3                NaN
4                NaN
              ...   
67108859    0.499803
67108860    0.502831
67108861    0.498991
67108862    0.496970
67108863    0.498349
Length: 67108864, dtype: float64
```

It takes relatively a long time to compute all these values, so one would want to store this result and only append future updates. To compute the last value for example i would only need to call the method using the last "window_size" values

```
values[nvalues - window_size:].ewm(span=window_size, min_periods=window_size).mean()
```

which returns something like this:

```
67108608         NaN
67108609         NaN
67108610         NaN
67108611         NaN
67108612         NaN
              ...   
67108859         NaN
67108860         NaN
67108861         NaN
67108862         NaN
67108863    0.497729
Length: 256, dtype: float64
```

As expected, everything but the last input is NaN and this way is relatively faster, but as you can see the EWM[67108863] is "very" different across each call and i can't get why, i believe the documentation is not clear for me as how the span parameter work, also, a few other similar stackOverflow posts suggested there aren't windows at all in the ewm method which confused me even more. Can somebody clarify this?

Comment: docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html

Comment: I read that, for me the alpha value on Yt expression would be "reseted" for every window of "span" size, but it seems thats not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, when calculating weighted averages, you need more than just the size of the windows because the calculations use data prior to that period.

In your case if you use 5x the size of window_size, you'll get the same last figure.

Full data set: 67108864 rows

```
values.ewm(span=window_size, min_periods=window_size).mean()

0               NaN
1               NaN
2               NaN
3               NaN
4               NaN
             ...
67108859   0.477958
67108860   0.479359
67108861   0.478963
67108862   0.479344
67108863   0.476700
Length: 67108864, dtype: float64
```

Reduced data set: 1280 rows (see the *5 in the slice)

```
values[nvalues - window_size*5:].ewm(span=window_size, min_periods=window_size).mean()
67107584        NaN
67107585        NaN
67107586        NaN
67107587        NaN
67107588        NaN
             ...
67108859   0.477958
67108860   0.479360
67108861   0.478963
67108862   0.479344
67108863   0.476700
Length: 1280, dtype: float64
```

Depending on the accuracy you are looking for, you can cut this back even further

Comment: Why though, I thought the idea behind ewm was similar to sma where each each value is computed on a given window except the elements are multiplied by a decaying weight which would be the same for each window? Also, does that mean that when you compute de ewm for the entire dataset de first few values returned are "wrong" due to not knowing prior values of the dataset? It feels that the data becomes incosistent.

Comment: Stock charts has a decent write-up on how to calc weighted average. They for example begin with a sma, then start the weightings. So, when I do analyses I drop off the first n rows to be sure the data is accurate 
httpss://school.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=technical_indicators:moving_averages